# Image not showing inside the modal

Tags: html, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I have a problem with the display of images. In the capture below you can see the disposition of my repositories.
    ---the page that must display images is a modal present in templates/agent/help/agentGuide.html. 
    ---the page that suppose to launch the modal is present in templates/agent/help.html,
    ---my images are in the folder img/help/

the problem is now in the modal: If I launch the modal in the browser I can see my images properly but in the physical device they dont appears (they are broken).
In the modal(templates/agent/help/agentGuide.html) I call my images like

I have tried to call them like  but nothing works.

I am testing it on android 5.1.1

[image: templates]
[image: img]

Comment: any errors are logged? can you add the code

Comment: there si no error but the image is showing will in the browser but in my android phone they appear as broken. my code is this one:

Answer (score 0):

My code is this one:

```
<!-- The container for How to login -->
<div class="list card">
    <div class="item item-body">
        <img class="full-image" src="img/loginForm.gif">
            <p>
                    Before to Login, the user must provide two information: the 
                    <strong>phone number</strong> and the 
                    <strong>password</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
                   <a class="subdued">*<strong class="assertive">NOTE</strong>: 
                   the provided phone number must have a full telephone format, 
                   i.e. <strong class="assertive">+XXXXXXXXXXXX</strong> where 
                   the 3 first symbols <strong>+XXX</strong> is the postal code 
                   for the country</a>
            </p>
    </div>
</div>
```